# Using the Unittest module in python to write non unit tests. Is it Bad practice?

Tags: python, unit-testing, integration-testing

Suppose I design a class, called A, in its own module.  Consider an abbreviation of what the code might look like.

```py
# file: A.py
class A:
  # define some useful behaviour for A class
  pass
```

Then I go on to perform some unit tests for this new class.  The tests would be roughly be carried out as shown below.

The reason for defining the **create_test_A** function outside of the TestA class will become apparent below.

```py
# file test_A.py
import A
import unittest

def create_test_A():
  # initialize into a useful test state before returning
  return A.A()

class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
  def test(self):
    new_A = create_test_A()
    # write some clever assertions about behaviour of new_A
    pass
```

Now suppose I build a new class, which is designed to work directly with instantiations of the A class.

```py
class A_bundle:
  def __init__(self):
    # define some fields that work with objects of type <class A>
    pass
```

When I go to write unit tests for this new class, my first instinct would be to create an instance of it, and then create a few objects of type A to interact with it.  Perhaps it would go like this.

```py
#file test_A_bundle.py

import test_A # this is the part I feel weird doing
import A_bundle
import unittest

class TestABundle(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_a_bundle(self):
    # create a couple of test objects of type A
    new_A1 = test_A.create_test_A()
    new_A2 = test_A.create_test_A()

    # make a new A_bundle to perform tests on
    new_bundle = A_bundle.A_bundle()

    # make some assertions about the way new_bundle
    # should interact with new_A1 and new_A2
```

Have I now gone outside the scope of unit testing and into the world of integration testing, since I'm not just testing the behaviour of the A_bundle class independently?

And if so, it seems that I could still use the unittest module in this way and run some useful tests.  Is this considered a bad practice?  That is, using the unittest module to write and perform tests that are not, in fact, unit tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my opinion you're still in the realm of unit tests, but I have a suggestion for you.

##### The hint

> Insert instances of the class `A` as arguments of the `__init__()` method of class `bundle_A`.

Following this hint I have modified your file `A_bundle.py` as following:

```
class A_bundle:
    def __init__(self, a1, a2):
        self.a1 = a1
        self.a2 = a2

    # define some fields that work with objects of type <class A>
    def sum(self):
        return self.a1.m_a() + self.a2.m_a()
```

I have also defined the method `sum()` in the class `A_bundle`: this is an example of *field that works with objects of type class A*.

##### Changes to class A

In the file `A.py`  I have define the attribute `x=10` and the method `m_a()` as followed:

```
# file: A.py
class A:
    x = 10
    def m_a(self):
        return self.x
```

##### Test methods in `test_A_bundle.py`

At the end I propose you a file `test_A_bundle.py` which contains 2 methods:

- your method `test_a_bundle()` which creates 2 real instances of class `A`, an instance of class `A_bundle` and verifies the result of the method `sum()`
- a second test method called `test_a_bundle_with_mock()` which substitutes the real instance of `A` by 2 Mock object and decide the return value of the method `m_a()` of this 2 Mock object

The code of `test_A_bundle.py` is the followed:

```
#file test_A_bundle.py

import test_A # this is the part I feel weird doing
import A_bundle
import unittest
from unittest import mock
import A

class TestABundle(unittest.TestCase):

    #+++++ YOUR TEST METHOD +++++
    def test_a_bundle(self):
        # create a couple of test objects of type A
        new_A1 = test_A.create_test_A()
        new_A2 = test_A.create_test_A()

        # make a new A_bundle to perform tests on (passes 2 instances of 
        # A to the __init__ method of A_bundle)
        new_bundle = A_bundle.A_bundle(new_A1, new_A2)
        self.assertEqual(20, new_bundle.sum())

    def test_a_bundle_with_mock(self):
        mock_a1 = mock.Mock()
        mock_a2 = mock.Mock()
        mock_a1.m_a.return_value = 20
        mock_a2.m_a.return_value = 30

        new_bundle = A_bundle.A_bundle(mock_a1, mock_a2)
        self.assertEqual(50, new_bundle.sum())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The second method shows you how to test the interaction between objects of class `A` and object of class `A_bundle` by **unit test**. On my opinion this test is not an integration test, it remains a unit test with tests the cooperation between classes.

Comment: Thanks so much for your great answer, and sorry it took so long for me to respond.